# Java jar path scanner

Tags: java, file, jar, path

I have a JAR with a text file in it. I want to read it using a Scanner

```
String path = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(str).getPath();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(path+"MyFile.txt"));
```

`path` contains the path to the JAR.
"MyFile.txt" is the file I want to read using a scanner.

It's not working and I'm not quite sure why. When I print out `path`, the actual file path looks like this `"file:/home..."`. I tried cutting off `"file:"` but that didn't seem to solve the issue.

What exactly am I doing wrong?